# Is the inverse of a M-Matrix again an M-Matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-congruences

**Is the inverse of a M-Matrix again an M-Matrix?**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is no.  See this thread on MO [Matrices whose inverse is positive](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91515/matrices-whose-inverse-is-positive).  There they use that $M$ matrices have non-negative inverses.  That is also stated on the wiki page:[M-Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix)

Comment: An exception might be diagonal matrices with positive diagonal.

Comment: Right, the inverse of a diagonal matrix is diagonal :P +1! :D